# Find pair within vector of maps

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector

I'm using the following function in an attempt to look up a key of a map element within a vector of maps.

```
Entry* SymTab::lookup(const char* name)
{
for (int i=0;i<table.size();i++) //table is the vector
 {
  map<const char*, Entry, ltstr>::iterator its= table.at(i).find(name); 
    if (its != cur.end())
    {
    Entry* obj = &its->second;
    cout<<(*its).first<<endl;
    return obj;
    }


  }
}
```

The function correctly returns the values of any item within the first vector index (at(0)). But it segfaults whenever I try to access an element within the second index (at(1)). I am sure that a map has been inserted correctly and populated at the second index.

Does anyone see the issue here?

Comment: What is `cur`? If you don't update it at each loop iteration, this will not recognize when an element is not there.

Comment: A map key of `const char*` is almost never a good idea.  How is the memory that the key points to managed?

Comment: If you want it to be readable to avoid such trouble in the future, I'd add some C++11 sugar: `Entry* SymTab::lookup(const std::string& name)`
    `{`
    `for (auto& cur: table) //table is the vector`
     `{`
      `auto its = cur.find(name); `
        `if (its != cur.end())`
        `{`
        `cout<<(*its).first<<endl;`
        `return &its->second;`
        `}`
      `}`
    `}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone see the issue here?

Yes. `cur` does not track the current map.

Try replacing the `if` line with:

```
if (its != table.at(i).end())
```